# Почему не работает запрос к Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Делаю функцию для регистрации пользователей. Сначала проверяю, существует ли такой телефон или нет, а после делаю запрос. Но почему-то запрос не хочет работать. `sch` - это моя схема. Работаю в Postgresql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sch.reg(
nam character varying,
l_name character varying,
o_name character varying,
addre address,
d_roz date,pol character varying,
phon integer,pas character varying,
num character varying,
let character varying,
n_fam character varying,
l_fam character varying,
o_fam character varying)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $$
    BEGIN
    if exists(select log from auth.login_phone where log = phon)
    then raise exception 'Уже существует такой телефон. В регистрации отказано';
    else
    insert into sch.pupil (name, last_name,name_otch, address, data_roz,d_pol, phone, pass,id_class,id_family,role)
    select nam,l_name,o_name,addre,d_roz,pol,phon,pas,sch.class.id_class,sch.family.id_family,1 FROM sch.family,sch.pupil,sch.class 
    where sch.family.name = n_fam and sch.family.last_name = l_fam and sch.name_otch = o_fam and sch.class.title = num 
    and sch.class.kurs = let and sch.pupil.id_family = sch.family.id_family and sch.pupil.id_class = sch.class.id_class;
    end if;     
    END;
    $$
```

Передаю такие параметры в фунциюю

```
select * from sch.reg('Умя','Умехин','Умеха','(г.Одесса,вул.Кисель,24,12)','2012.01.01','Мужчина',325689742,'11','1','А','Ульнов',
                     'Сергиевич','Коваленку')
```

Однако когда ввожу данные мне пишет ОШИБКУ

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sch" LINE 3: ...name =
>   n_fam and sch.family.last_name = l_fam and sch.name_o...

Не могу понять, почему ругается на схему....

Comment: Проблему с этой ошибкой нашел. Сейчас ругаеться почему-то на мйо составной ТИП address `ERROR:  column "address" is of type sch.address but expression is of type address
LINE 2: select nam,l_name,o_name,addre,d_roz,pol,phon,pas,c.id_class...`

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут `… and sch.name_otch = o_fam and …` между именем столбца и именем схемы пропущено имя таблицы